# Firebase Unity SDK: How to get all registered Users

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I want to get the usernames of all registered users in my Firebase project. I have installed `FirebaseAuth.unitypackage`.

I have looked to the [Unity Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/manage-users) in Firebase but found nothing about this. What i want is given [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users). But there are some problems;

1. It is made with Admin SDK, I am not sure that this SDK can be installed for Unity. There is no package in the SDK named Admin.
2. C# code is not given.
3. A note has been left as *"Note: This API is currently only available for the Admin Node.js SDK"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer this in the context of keeping everything in Firebase and being willing to pull in other Firebase products. If you want to use the Auth Admin SDK in general, just make sure that you do it from a server you control (as opposed to a user's machine).

In general, you typically need one more Firebase service to interact with Firebase Auth in the way you want to. Either use Cloud Functions with the Node.js admin SDK (which I don't like using the admin SDK in your critical user path just out of caution) or to use something like Realtime Database to keep a separate list of all your users and any additional information you might associate with them.

I'll typically store my registered users in [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database), with a node named `users` and then each user having a node just named their user id. So a user list with two users whose IDs are uid_0 and uid_1, I'd have a structure like:

- users:

  - uid_0: {name, avatar, &c}
  - uid_1: {name, avatar, &c}

Your rules.json could look something like this to only allow users write their own userid data but let everyone read it (so you can give your users a user list):

```
{
  "rules": {
    // Bonus maps cannot be written to under normal circumstances.
    "users": {
      ".write": "!data.exists()",
      "$uid" {
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".read": true // or more granular, like ensure your uid is in the target's friends list
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As far as maintaining this list. You can either use the [rules language](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules) to ensure that users can only create/delete their own $uid or use [Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) with [Firebase Authentication triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events) (and that [Realtime Database Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start) I try to minimize my usage of) to add/remove entries to the users list.

I hope this helps!